# Receiver type 'AsynchImageView' for instance method dose not declare a method with selector 'loadImageFromURL'

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uiimageview

I am nubie in ios & using this and gatting error :

**Receiver type 'AsynchImageView' for instance method dose not declare a method with selector 'loadImageFromURL'**

```
NSString * url = @"http://www.iphonejd.com/.a/6a010535fde333970c0120a90cc5b9970b-pi";
AsyncImageView *asyncImageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,32,100, 100)];   
[asyncImageView loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[cell.profile_picImage addSubview:asyncImageView];
[asyncImageView release];
```

*can any one help me ?
        Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AsyncImageView looks like subclass of UIView or similar. But you use method -loadImageFromURL: of [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView). Check what  you use correct AsyncImageView.

Comment: Thanks, i was using incorrect class also didn't declare properties for it in custom cell for show image view..